# Oracle loop compare value Or get all changed value

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, triggers

I want to log all the change what user make in sql by trigger 
for example

```
  create table XXX (
    a ....,
    b ....,
    c ....
  )
```

if user commit sql

```
 update XXX set a = '1' ,b = '1' where c = ?
```

in trigger

I want to log two record

---

content

---

column a change from '0' to '1'

---

column b change from '0' to '2'

because c is not change so dont log c(suppose this record a and b values 0 by default)

Comment: use a before update trigger on each row and check the :old.a and :new.a against each other.

Comment: Compare each column in `:OLD` and `:NEW` to decide if it needs to be logged.

Comment: @KevinEsche if  I dont know  how many field in this table  how can I loop for the record and compare their value?for example if this select get one record  and has four field  a,b,c,d, how to control loop times?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax  if I dont know how many field in this table how can I loop for the record and compare their value?for example if this select get one record and has four field a,b,c,d, how to control loop times?

Comment: @Wangbo The implicit looping (for which you do not have to provide control structures) is over *records*. Thus the number of columns is irrelevant for loop control.

Comment: @collapsar sorry, more detail plz

Comment: @Wangbo The update statement affects a set of records from your table. The suitable triggers are applied to each record of this set. The host variables `:old` and `:new` hold the record before and after the update, respectively. In this programming model there is no such thing as looping (though implicitly there is a 'looping' in the sense that each of the affected records is visited in turn).

Comment: @collapsar I see , thank you